How to solve such complicated integrals in MATLAB?
I am trying to code the following expression involving four integrals in MATLAB but its not running properly: \begin{multline}
     P_1^o=\int_{z_2=0}^{\infty}\int_{z_1=0}^{\infty}\int_{h=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=0}^{y_{max}}\frac{1}{\Gamma(m_0)} \gamma\biggl (m_0, \frac{u_1/\biggl({{\begin{array}{c}a_1 \zeta y |g_1|^2 h \rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)}- u_1 a_2 \zeta y |g_1|^2 h \rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)}- \\u_1 a_1 \zeta |g_1|^2 h z_1- u_1 a_1 \zeta {\rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)}} z_2 |g_1|^2 h \\-u_1 a_2 \zeta |g_1|^2 h z_1- u_1 a_2 \zeta {\rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)}} z_2 |g_1|^2 h\end{array}}}\biggr)}{\Omega_0/m_0}\biggr)\\ \cdot
     f_Y(y) \cdot f_H(h) \cdot f_{Z_1}(z_1)\cdot f_{Z_2}(z_2) \text{d}y \text{d}h \text{d}z_1 \text{d}z_2
\end{multline}
where $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(m_0)} \left(\frac{m_0}{\Omega_0}\right)^{m_0} y^{m_0-1} \exp\left(-\frac{m_0 y}{\Omega_0}\right)$, $f_H(h) = \frac{1}{2\pi A_1}$,\
$f_{Z_1}(z_1) = \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 z_1}
$, $f_{Z_2}(z_2) = \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 z_2},  y_\text{max}=\biggl( \frac{{ \rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)} (a_1-u_1 a_2)}}{{\begin{array}{c} u_1 a_1 Z_1+ u_1 a_1 {\rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)}} Z_2 +u_1 a_2 Z_1+ u_1 a_2 {\rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)}} Z_2 \end{array}}}\biggr)$.
This is what I had tried so far:
integrand = @(y, h, z1, z2) (1 / gamma(m_0)) * ...
            gammainc( ((u_1 ./ ...
            (a_1 * zeta_1 * y .* g_1_abs_sq .* h .* P_h1_2 - ...
            u_1 * a_2 * zeta_1 * y .*  g_1_abs_sq .* h .*P_h1_2 - ...
            u_1 * a_1 * zeta_1 *  g_1_abs_sq .* h .* z1 - ...
            u_1 * a_1 * zeta_1 *P_h1_2 * z2 .* g_1_abs_sq .* h - ...
            u_1 * a_2 * zeta_1 * g_1_abs_sq .* h .* z1 - ...
            u_1 * a_2 * zeta_1 * P_h1_2 * z2 .* g_1_abs_sq .* h)) / ...
            (Omega_0 / m_0)),m_0) .* ...
            (1/gamma(m_0))*((m_0/Omega_0)^m_0)*y^(m_0-1)*exp(-m_0*y/Omega_0).* 1/(2*pi*a_11).*lambda_1*exp(-lambda_1*z1).*lambda_2*exp(-lambda_2*z2);

% Define the outer integral with respect to z2 from 0 to infinity
        outer_integral = @(z2) arrayfun(@(z2_val) integral(@(y,h,z1) integrand(y,h,z1,z2_val ), 0, y_max(z2_val)), 0:1000);
    

    % Perform the integration
   op = integral(outer_integral, 0, 1000);

I am not getting what mistake I am doing. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

It’s not clear what you problem is. Are you getting an error or is the output not what you expect (and if so, why)?

Also, make sure to read the documentation for Matlab’s incomplete gamma function, gammainc, as it my be defined slightly differently from your equation.
